# How to check for specific prop in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to control url input. For that I created types:

```
type Sort = 'best-match' | 'price' | 'new';

type Price = number;

export default { Sort, Price }
```

In my file I have object:

```
import urlTypes from './types';

const acceptedProps = {
  sort: {
    show: true,
    type: urlTypes.Sort
  }
}
```

There will be more accepted props in object. Currently I'm getting error:

```
'Sort' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

I want to check if my url prop key exists in `acceptedProps` and if yes, then make sure that `val` matches that type. How can I do it?

```
const params = router.query.param;
params.forEach((value)=>{
  const [key, val] = value.split('_');
  if(acceptedProps.hasOwnProperty(key)) // check if val matches acceptedProperty[key].type
})
```

There will be more accepted props in object. Currently I'm getting error:

Comment: `acceptedProps` is a constant and not a type/interface.. so as the error says you are indeed using type as value

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is a misunderstanding of how to type objects.

The accepted props should be written like this:

```
import urlTypes from './types';

const acceptedProps: {
  sort: {
    show: boolean,
    type: urlTypes.Sort,
  }
} = {
  sort: {
    show: true,
    type: 'best-match'
  }
}
```

which could more clearly be written like this:

```
import urlTypes from './types';

type AcceptedPropsType = {
  sort: {
    show: boolean,
    type: urlTypes.Sort,
  }
}

const acceptedProps: AcceptedPropsType = {
  sort: {
    show: true,
    type: 'best-match'
  }
}
```

This is assuming that your logic for what props an object accepts shouldn't itself be implemented with TypeScript (but I don't have enough context to say either way)